# Converting multiple rows to single XML row. - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have one table in following format.

[image]

I want data in XML format per Employee using SQL query as below

```
<Employee>
  <EmployeeID>1</EmployeeID>
  <FirstName>Jon</FirstName>
  <LastName>Snow</LastName>
  <City>North of the wall</City>
  <Age>28</Age>
  <Gender>Male</Male>
</Employee>

<Employee>
  <EmployeeID>2</EmployeeID>
  <FirstName>Arya</FirstName>
  <LastName>Stark</LastName>
  <City>Winterfell</City>
  <Age>14</Age>
  <Gender>Female</Male>
</Employee>
```

I have tried using query,

```
SELECT  DISTINCT EmployeeID ,(  
    SELECT   
    EmployeeID,  
    (SELECT    PDFKey ,   
        Replace(Value,char(CAST(0x001A as int)),'') as Value  FROM TempData EE WHERE  E.EmployeeID =EE.EmployeeID FOR XML PATH(''),   
    TYPE, ELEMENTS)   
    AS Employee  
    FROM   
    TempData E WHERE o.EmployeeID =E.EmployeeID  
    GROUP BY EmployeeID  
    FOR XML AUTO, ELEMENTS  
    ) AS XMLtag FROM TempData O
```

But it gives data in format like,

```
 <E>
 <EmployeeID>1</EmployeeID>
 <Employee>
    <PDFKey>FirstName</PDFKey>
    <Value>Jon</Value>
    <PDFKey>LastName</PDFKey>
    <Value>Snow</Value>
    <PDFKey>City</PDFKey>
    <Value>North of the wall</Value>
    <PDFKey>Age</PDFKey>
    <Value>28</Value>
    <PDFKey>Gender</PDFKey>
    <Value>Male</Value>
  </Employee>
  </E>
```

**And I want one row per employee which will have 2 columns, EmployeeID and XMLdata.**

Please refer image below for expected output,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8syi.jpg)

Comment: Be more specific with your question.  What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use PIVOT + FOR XML PATH:

```
SELECT  *
FROM Employee
PIVOT (
    MAX([Value]) FOR PDFKey IN ([FirstName],[LastName],[City],[Age],[Gender])
) as u
FOR XML PATH('Employee'), TYPE
```

Output:

```
<Employee>
  <EmployeeID>1</EmployeeID>
  <FirstName>Jon</FirstName>
  <LastName>Snow</LastName>
  <City>North of the wall</City>
  <Age>28</Age>
  <Gender>Male</Gender>
</Employee>
<Employee>
  <EmployeeID>2</EmployeeID>
  <FirstName>Arya</FirstName>
  <LastName>Stark</LastName>
  <City>Winterfell</City>
  <Age>14</Age>
  <Gender>Female</Gender>
</Employee>
```

After pivoting you will get table like this:

```
EmployeeID  FirstName   LastName    City                Age Gender
1           Jon         Snow        North of the wall   28  Male
2           Arya        Stark       Winterfell          14  Female
```

After that you add FOR XML with PATH mode

> In PATH mode, column names or column aliases are treated as XPath
>   expressions. These expressions indicate how the values are being
>   mapped to XML. Each XPath expression is a relative XPath that provides
>   the item type., such as the attribute, element, and scalar value, and
>   the name and hierarchy of the node that will be generated relative to
>   the row element.

Also I have added TYPE

> SQL Server support for the xml (Transact-SQL) enables you to
>   optionally request that the result of a FOR XML query be returned as
>   xml data type by specifying the TYPE directive.

**EDIT**

```
;WITH cte AS (
SELECT  *
FROM Employee
PIVOT (
    MAX([Value]) FOR PDFKey IN ([FirstName],[LastName],[City],[Age],[Gender])
) as u
)

SELECT  e.EmployeeID,
        (SELECT *
        FROM cte
        WHERE EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID
        FOR XML PATH('Employee'), TYPE) as XMLData
FROM cte e
```

Output:

```
EmployeeID  XMLData
1           <Employee><EmployeeID>1</EmployeeID><FirstName>Jon</FirstName><LastName>Snow</LastName><City>North of the wall</City><Age>28</Age><Gender>Male</Gender></Employee>
2           <Employee><EmployeeID>2</EmployeeID><FirstName>Arya</FirstName><LastName>Stark</LastName><City>Winterfell</City><Age>14</Age><Gender>Female</Gender></Employee>
```

Comment: This query works perfectly, but I need  one row per employee which will have 2 columns, EmployeeID and XMLdata.

Comment: @gofr1, Great answer, +1 from my side... My magic glass bulb tells me, that OP actually wants the output as `EmployeeID` as `INT` column and the rest (possibly containing the ID) as XML within a second column. Easily achieved with a sub-select...

Comment: Please refer "https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8syi.jpg", I want output in this format.

Comment: @Shnugo Thanks, I was unable to explain my actual query.

Comment: @AbhijeetKhandagale I changed answer, hope, this will help you.

Comment: @Shnugo Thanks for clarifying!

Comment: @AbhijeetKhandagale My pleasure!